# Implementing a QAction in the menu bar

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement something like the below in Qt:

[image]

Basically the user can click on the empty box (to the left of `"Average"`) to spawn a new dialog box. And also the user can click on `"Average"` to perform another function.

I understand that `QWidgetAction` can achieve this, but I was wondering if there is any simpler way to achieve this; or does `QAction` itself already has such a functionality.

Comment: _the user can click on the empty box (to the left of "Average") to spawn a new dialog box._ What about a [`QPushButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html)?

Comment: @Scheff Yes to clarify, I am more of looking at two functions inside a single `QAction`. Clicking on `Average` runs one function, clicking on the empty box runs another function.

Comment: Please, consider to add a [mcve]. (Sorry, I cannot see your image "enter image description here" - blocked on my side.)

Comment: Two functions inside a single `QAction` couldn't be a problem. Running either/or depending on mouse click position is IMHO a bad idea. What if the action was triggered by something else than a mouseclick? Wouldn't it be easier to have two widgets - each with it's own action?

Comment: Just at home, I had a look onto your snapshot. That brought me to another idea which might be interesting for you as well: In our appl., there is e.g. an edit action which is used in context menus and toolbars. Per default, it (re-)uses an already opened dialog (if there is one). Alternatively, the user might want a new dialog (e.g. to compare or copy things). Finally, we decided to evaluate state of the [CTRL] button for this. It's easy to retrieve its state from everywhere (it's global in Qt), and it works independently how action was actually fired (mouse, keyboard, double-click).

Comment: ... and, until now, I couldn't recognize any annoying interference of our "CTRL extension" with the standard interaction handling of Qt. (I mean, adding specific interaction handling to your application bears always the danger of "overriding" or breaking something which is already provided by Qt widgets.)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your suggestions and advice. I decided to split it up into seperate QAction functionalities instead since it is much easier to implement and does away with all the pesky stylesheet issues too.